# OneDrive Custom Properties

Tags: rest, properties, metadata, onedrive

I would like to store some additional metadata with documents that I am uploading to OneDrive using the REST interface.  Does anyone know if this is possible at this time?  An example might be a hash value that would help me detect alterations without relying on time stamps.

I can't use "Comments" because they are inside the user's field of view which would cause confusion.

Embedding data in the documents themselves is not an option.  I don't control document formats.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Custom/extended metadata is not currently supported by the Live API for OneDrive.